# Express page changes based on time of day

Tags: javascript, date, express, dynamic, pug

Putting together a project that requires me to use two different pug files,and the one being used changes based on the time of day (i.e. night.pug is active from 7:00pm to 7:00am and day.pug is active from 7:00am to 7:00pm)

What I'm asking is, how would I go about rendering these pages? I know I'll implement new Date().getHours(); to get the system time, but I'm not entirely sure how I'm going to render the pages conditionally. Are two different app.get's necessary?

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(express.static('resources'));

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');

app.get()

const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log(`Started server on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

app.get is currently empty because I have no idea how to approach this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be something like this. Haven't tested it but should help you get started. I just tweaked the code on the express documentation page.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // Get the current hour (you might need to do the UTC thing)
  const currentHour = (new Date()).getHours();
  // between 7am and 7pm on a 24 hour clock
  const isDay = currentHour > 7 && currentHour < 19;
  // Determine which template to render
  if (isDay) {
    res.render('day', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' });
  } else {
    res.render('night', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' });
  }
});
```

Documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html